# Trying to remove 1 digit from an array and return the array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, int

I want to remove the first digit of my array and return the array without the first term

`new_array` always comes out as just a single number

`n` is an integer

```
array = (n.to_s).split(//)

print array

new_array = array.delete_at(0)

puts new_array
```

Comment: Your question sounds a bit ambiguous. Do you want to delete the 1st element from `array` (i.e. altering `array`) or do you just want a new array without the 1st element? (i.e. without altering `array`)

Comment: BTW, your code `(n.to_s).split(//)` returns an array of characters, not an array of digits.

Comment: Write a new method which runs the last two lines of code you have written.

Answer (score 2):

Drops first n elements from Array and returns the rest of the elements in an array.

```
 a = [41,42,43,45,46]
 => [41, 42, 43, 45, 46] 
 a.drop 1
 => [42, 43, 45, 46]
```

Comment: `drop` doesn't delete elements from the existing array, it returns a new array without those elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-digits) and [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) this way:

```
n = 12345678
position = 3
n.digits.reverse.tap { |ary| ary.delete_at(position) }

#=> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

`position = 0` remove the firs digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):001:0> arr = (1..10).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
irb(main):002:0> arr.shift
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> arr
=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I hope that helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use array method `drop` to delete n number of elements from array

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.drop 2
=> [3, 4, 5]
```

ref: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-drop

Comment: `drop` doesn't delete elements from the existing array, it returns a _new_ array without those elements.

Comment: True, the requirement is to return a new array without first element. hope it would serve the purpose

Answer (score -1):

Because `delete_at` returns the deleted item.
If you want to remove and retrieve at the same time for the first item, you can use -

`new_array = array.drop(1)`

Comment: how do i do the same thing but with any position in the array

Comment: There is no predefined method for this in ruby.
BTW delete_at method already deleted the item from the original array, so you can use it.
Or you can assign it to a new variable in the next line.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have not checked it, I have updated the answer.